# How to save figure from Jupyter notebook to local, while the notebook lives on a remote server?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am using Chrome at local (Windows 10) machine, and my jupyter notebook runs on a remote server (Linux). I would like to batch generate figures and save to local hard disk. Is there a easy way doing so?

I can of course use right click in Chrome to save picture. But for tons of figures, it becomes tedious.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an easy way to do it. You have to save the figures as if you are on the server (Linux machine). You can save them in a folder on your Linux machine and sync it to your windows (using rsync). This can be automated in your python script if your local (Windows) machine could be a server by, for instance, creating a `savefig` function:

```py
def savefig(fn):
    plt.savefig("fig/{}".format(fn))
    os.system("rsync -tvh fig/\* your-windows:dir/to/fig/")
```

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming you are drawing plots with matplotlib.

What about using [matplotlib `savefig`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html) in your batch? The figures will be saved on the remote node, but you can download them as a bundle with `scp` or other.

Example:

```
plt.savefig("test.png")
```